# How to store colon separated strings in hashtable?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that gets response from another script as JSON,

```
$resp = & ".\script1.ps1" | ConvertFrom-Json

$resp[1]
```

and I get the following output:

```
abc    :  1234
defghjk:  897
klm    :  something12
```

Now i want to store those as keys/values in hashtable

```
$hash = @{}

$($resp[1]) | ForEach-Object {
    # Split each pair into key and value
    $key,$value = $_.Split(':')
    # Populate $hash
    $hash[$key] = $value
}

return $hash
```

I get the following error:

> Method invocation failed because
>   [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not contain a
>   method named 'Split'

and

> Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null. At
>   $hash[$key] = $value

---

**UPDATE: With this i am able to output the Key, Value, and Name**

```
$resp[1].PSObject.Properties | Foreach { $hash[$_.Key] = $_.Value }

return $hash
```

I get back:

```
Key : abc
Value : 1234
Name: abc

Key : defghjk
Value : 897
Name: defghjk
```

and so on...

suppose i have a SQL table as follows

[image: table]

and I have the following query to get the ID:

```
$DB_ID = Query "select ID from table where DB = 'cube1'" | Select -ExpandProperty ID;
```

How do i get the value based on `$DB_ID` match with Key/Name and store the value in a variable say `$password`?

in other words, i am looking for something like this:

```
$password = $hash.value where $hash.key -match `$DB_ID`
```

so then the password in this case (cube1) would be: 1234 because the key abc would match abc from table

---

**UPDATE2**: Now that i think about it, i probably didnt even need to hash the response to begin with. mayb i can do something like this, right?:

```
$password = $resp[1].PSObject.Properties.value where $resp[1].PSObject.Properties.key -match $DB_ID
```

Comment: A PScustomobject is a set of name-value pairs.  They are not strings separated by colons like you get when you query the variable. Try something like this ```$hashtable = @{}
foreach( $property in $myobject.psobject.properties.name )
{
    $hashtable[$property] = $myObject.$property
}``` from [powershellexplained.com](https://powershellexplained.com/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject/)

Comment: @Brian so i cant store the colon seperated strings as keys/values in hash?

Comment: You can convert it to a hash table.  But it does not have the structure you are looking at when you see it displayed with colons.

Comment: If you use PowerShell 6 you can now do `ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable`

Comment: @Cataster - pro'ly not! [*grin*] a hashtable _requires_ unique keys and your PSObject has properties that common to each object. so, for ONE object, yes, you can make a hashtable of the props as keys and the values of those props as values to those keys.

Comment: @MarkWragg thats neat!! unfortunately its on our development server so version 5 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `PSCustomObject` is basically already keys and values, it's a proper object - it just outputs with the `:` as a friendly way to display the information to you. The left side of the `:` is the key and the right side is the value. If you want it to be a proper hashtable though, you'll have to do iterate over the properties like so:

```
$myHash = @{}
$resp[1].PSObject.Properties | Foreach { $myHash[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
```

The way this works is that `PSCustomObject` has a `PSObject` property from which you can get the properties from. Iterate over each property on the `PSCustomObject`, and set the property name as a key in `$myHash`, and the value of the same property as the value of that key in `$myHash`.

#### UPDATE RESPONSE

You would access those like follows: `$myHash['cube1']` and `$myHash['cube2']`.

If you already know the target `$DB_ID` ahead of time, and the desired returned object from that script already organizes a DB to an ID you can do this: `$myHash[$DB_ID]`.

You actually don't even need to convert it to a hashtable to do that, either. You can simply use the original `PSCustomObject` you converted from JSON like so:

`$resp[1].$DB_ID` or `$resp[1]."$DB_ID"`

Comment: nice, now when i return the hashtable, i get Key, Value, and Name. how do i access thhe keys? for example, lets say i have a table that has databases and ID's corresponding to them. i will have a query that will retrieve the ID based on the database name i enter in the script param argument. I would like to match the ID to the same Key (Name) that matches and get its value. suppose i store the query result in a variable called $DB_ID. how would i compare the keys to $DB_ID and fetch the value for that and set the value as lets say $password?

Comment: I'm not understanding, are `key`, `value`, and `name` the property names on the original custom object, and you're asking how to retrieve those items from the hashtable?

Comment: Also out of curiosity, why are you converting this to a hashtable instead of working with the `PSCustomObject` object proper?

Comment: check UPDATE section in my post to see why i am doing that and what i am trying ot do

Comment: would i be doing this correctly: $password = $hash.value where $hash.key -match `$DB_ID`? or are you saying i dont need to use a hashtable for this, i can access it directly as pscutomobject? $password = $resp[1].PSObject.Properties.value where $resp[1].PSObject.Properties.key -match `$DB_ID`

Comment: See my updated response - you can do this far more gracefully. Keep in mind that `where` clauses have the potential to return more than one thing, and technically speaking will return a collection. Also, I'm fairly certain your `Where-Object` syntax is incorrect in the first place.

Comment: ohhh i think youre mistaking the table. the table picture is supposedly a SQL table, not the hashtable. the hashtable would be these: Key : abc
Value : 1234
Name: abc

Key : defghjk
Value : 897
Name: defghjk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193290/discussion-between-cataster-and-bender-the-greatest).